# CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED: invalid or inconsistent certificate extension(handshake.cc.359)

Tags: android, flutter, dart, https, ssl-certificate

This problem only occurs when running my app on Android (Emulator or Physical Device). It's fine on iOS.

I'm getting this error when calling a GET request to my server protected with SSL.

```
HandshakeException: Handshake error in client (OS Error: I/flutter (11617):   CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED: invalid or inconsistent certificate extension(handshake.cc:359))
```

The SSL Certificate is not self-signed. It is signed by my company's own isolated CA. And the CA is 3 tiers (1 root certificate and 2 intermediate certificates underneath). The last intermediate authority is the one that signed the Server Certificate so the chain of trust is 3 levels.

Certificate details

1. CA and IA keys are 512 bits long and uses SHA-512 digestions
2. The server certificate key is 2048 bits long with a SHA-256 digestion
3. The extended key usage of the server certificate is only server authentication
4. The server certificate is also end-entry

I have added the server certificate and the chain of trust to the app itself under my /assets/raw/ directory
and have added these to my securityContext (using iOClient for making http calls)

Flutter doctor results

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.2.2, on macOS 11.4 20F71 darwin-x64, locale en-PH)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 4.2)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.57.1)
[✓] Connected device (3 available)
    ! Error: Gabe’s iPhone is busy: Copying cache files from device. Xcode will continue when Gabe’s iPhone is finished. (code -10)

• No issues found!
```

Answer (score 0):

I solve this by adding one line to android/app/src/debug/AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<application android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"/>
```

Comment: This is good for when I want to use HTTP and not HTTPS. But in my case, I'm using HTTPS.

Comment: @GabrielRobles have you checked this link [link](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/50699)

Comment: Yes I've read the thread and also the article. But none of those are what I'm looking for. It's either a setting I need to fix in the Android side (since the problem is only occurring on Android) or something I have to update on the Server Certificate

Comment: I cannot guarantee that the following is the solution, but try to concatenate the authority certificates in a bottom-up manner. For example, if you have a root certificate, an intermediate certificate and a server certificate (1st, 2nd and 3rd levels respectively) the certificate order inside the .crt file should be: server, intermediate and root.